# how to display nivo slider in home page in nopcommerece n theme

Tags: slider, nopcommerce, nivo-slider

hi i have added a few products but nivo slider (homepageslider)  is not showing up in the home page. I am using a themed nopcommerce installation

http://www.n-theme.com/products/19-gifts1_90.aspx

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please goto admin side->Content Management -> Widget
   1)Please enable if "Nivo Slider" is not active.
   2)If enable then Configuration properly

Make sure it's Help for you